# PowerShell PictureBox Object in a New Runspace - Not Showing

Tags: powershell, hashtable, picturebox, synchronized, runspace

I have a button click event handler that runs commands. I wanted to add a spinning wheel GIF for the user experience.
I added a picturebox object with the GIF as the image.

If I change the visibility at the start of the event ($pictureboxLoading.Visible = $true) the spinning wheel will freeze/stop spinning when the next command is run. This is normal because Windows Forms uses one thread and freezes the GUIs pipeline while commands are being run. I know this.
My solution was to then create a new runspace with a synchronized hashtable that includes the picturebox object in it and change the visibility in the runspace and then continue with other code before making it invisible again.

Two issues arose from that:

1. The visibility of the picturebox isn't changing inside the runspace or it is and then changing back when the runspace is closed, which with only one command would happen instantly making it seem like nothing happened. I accidentally found a way to trigger the visibility by adding a MessageBox Show() function, but this leads to the second issue
2. I need something to trigger the visibility for some reason and keep the runspace open until I am done with the rest of my code and then I will manually change the visibility to $false again at the end of the click event.

Here is a sample of what I did:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    $SyncHash.Loading.Visible = $true
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("test", "Test", "OK", "Information")
}

# Setup hash table
$SyncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{ })
$SyncHash.Loading = $pictureboxLoading

$runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$runspace.ThreadOptions = "UseNewThread"
$runspace.Open()
$runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("SyncHash", $SyncHash)
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($Scriptblock)
$psCmd.Runspace = $runspace
$data = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
```

I added a label to the form to test if the runspace was working and the label's text changed from "inside" to "done" so I know it works. It's just the picture box object that doesn't work.

Any ideas?